# Why is Windows auditing svchost by default?

Tags: logging, audit

I would like to know why, by default, Windows set an audit rules on svchost.exe ?
While it's used only when auditing is active, i don't understand why there's a special treatment for this file since auditing is disabled by default anyway.

Comment: It seems that other files and folders are also audited by default (explorer.exe , \Windows\Boot, \Windows\SystemResources...). It becomes a problem when Remote Desktop is used by many users, the log grows a lot.